# A question about oaths

Tags: forgiveness, oaths, lying, helping

Asalamualaykum this is a question regarding about oaths. If you make an oath saying you won't lie then don't fulfill it and for example let's say you lied a lot do you have to expiate each of the lies you made or you saying you wont lie anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If  you have sworn in the blessed name of Allah and you have broken it deliberately ,  you must pay [Al-Kaffarah](https://fa.wikipedia.org/wiki/%DA%A9%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%87) for every time you swore and then break your oath. Al-Kaffarah includes feeding ten poor people, or giving clothes  to ten poor people. if you can not do that, you must fast for three days.

if you accidentally break the oath or you were forced to break the oath, there is no need to Al-Kaffarah.
if the oath was not in the name of Allah, Imams or  prophets, Quran, , there is no need to Al-Kaffarah.
[reference](https://www.pasokhgoo.ir/node/60527)